# Basic Probability Analysis Using Bins In R

Tags: r, statistics

I'm not a statistician, but I do want to use basic probability to understand what's happening with my data.

I've created a cumbersome but very helpful method of looking at my data in specific bins using histograms then comparing the different groups I'm interested in analyzing to the overall group. It's showed us some incredible insights at our company and it's easy to explain what's happening in the graph. That being said though it's pretty tedious and it would make sense that this type of analysis is so useful that others would have created a function for it already.

Here's my code below. Does this type of analysis already exist in a function? Also I've used logi.hist.plot() which does something similar, but it can be problematic and I prefer using this "raw view" of the data.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

#Create the data
set.seed(84102)
daba <- data.frame(YES_NO = c(0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1))
daba$UserCount <-     c(23,43,45,65,32,10,34,68,65,75,43,24,37,54,73,29,87,32,21,12)

#Create the bins using hist(), clean up bins and make them integers
hist_breaks <- cut(daba$UserCount, breaks = hist(daba$UserCount, breaks =     20)$breaks)
daba$Breaks <- hist_breaks
daba$Breaks <- sub(".*,","",daba$Breaks)
daba$Breaks <- sub("]","",daba$Breaks)
daba$Breaks[is.na(daba$Breaks)] <- 0
daba$Breaks <- as.integer(daba$Breaks)

#Create two data groups to be compared
daba_NO  <- filter(daba, daba$YES_NO == 0)
daba_YES <- filter(daba, daba$YES_NO == 1)

#Aggregate user count into histogram bins using aggregate()
daba_NOAgg <- aggregate(data = daba_NO, daba_NO$Breaks~daba_NO$UserCount, sum)
daba_YESAgg <- aggregate(data = daba_YES, daba_YES$Breaks~daba_YES$UserCount, sum)

#Rename the columns to clean it up
colnames(daba_NOAgg) <- c("UserCountNo", "Breaks")
colnames(daba_YESAgg) <- c("UserCountYes", "Breaks")

#Merge the two groups back together
daba_SUMAgg <- merge(x = daba_NOAgg, y = daba_YESAgg, by.x = "Breaks", by.y = "Breaks")

#Generate basic probability for Yes group of users
daba_SUMAgg$Probability <-     (daba_SUMAgg$UserCountYes/(daba_SUMAgg$UserCountNo+daba_SUMAgg$UserCountYes))*100

#Graph the data
ggplot(data = daba_SUMAgg)+
  geom_point(alpha = 0.4, mapping = aes(y = daba_SUMAgg$Probability, x =     daba_SUMAgg$Breaks))+
  labs( x = "BINS", y = "PROBABILITY", title = "PROBABILITY ANALYSIS USING     BINS")


daba_SUMAgg
```

Comment: Are you sure your `daba_SUMAgg` data frame makes sense? You get 2 rows for breaks 25 and 35. Also, some of your breaks, like 90, as missing.

Comment: I think you need `aggregate(data = daba_NO, daba_NO$UserCount~daba_NO$Breaks, sum)`. You have to switch what you pass to `~`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to split your dataset when you have `group_by` of `dplyr`. No need to create numeric values from your ranges to plot. I think your process misses something (see my comment above).

I'd suggest to use

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

#Create the data
set.seed(84102)
daba <- data.frame(YES_NO = c(0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1))
daba$UserCount <-     c(23,43,45,65,32,10,34,68,65,75,43,24,37,54,73,29,87,32,21,12)

daba %>%
  mutate(Breaks = cut(UserCount, breaks = hist(UserCount, breaks = 20)$breaks, right = F)) %>%  # create your breaks (use right = F other wise you miss the value 10)
  group_by(Breaks, YES_NO) %>%                             # for every range and YES_NO value
  summarise(UserCount = sum(UserCount)) %>%                # get sum of counts
  mutate(Prc = UserCount/sum(UserCount)) %>%               # get the probability / percentage
  ungroup() %>%                                            # forget the grouping
  mutate(YES_NO = factor(YES_NO)) %>%                      # change this to factor for the plot
  ggplot(aes(Breaks, Prc, col=YES_NO, group=YES_NO)) +     # plot
  geom_point() +
  geom_line()
```

Run the piped process step by step to see how the data processing works and how the dataset looks before it gets plotted.